# How to submit Jquery ajax function without page refresh?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've read other posts from other users having a similar problem, but they all seem to want the ajax to replace something on a page.

In my case however, my ajax is just pertaining to a user clicking 'like' on an image. I just want their like to register, without a page refresh. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code below?

```
<script>
    function submitLikeForm()  {
        var form = jQuery("#like_form");
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "GET", 
                url: form.attr("action"), 
                data: form.serialize(), 
                success:   function() 
            });
        }
    </script>
```

And here is my form (it's being echoed in a large PHP file so I didn't want to paste the entire thing, just the relevant part):

```
<form name='like_form' id='like_form' action='liked_button.php'>
   <input type='image' img src='https://i.imgur.com/pMmYaYM.jpg' class='like_button button' name='like_button' onClick='return submitLikeForm()'>
   <input type='hidden' name='hidden_image' class='hidden_image' value='$image_info'>
   <input type='hidden' name='hidden_folder' class='hidden_folder' value='$random_directory'>
   <input type='hidden' name='hidden_name' class='hidden_name' value='$image_name'>
   <input disabled type='text' name='total_likes' class='total_likes' value='$liked_count'>
 </form>
```

The form is sent to a php page where I can get values and store them in a table.

Comment: see your `success` method - it seems to have a syntax error. Add the `{}` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your success function. Try using the developer console in your browser to catch errors like that.  Also, I think you need to add `return false` to make sure the page doesn't reload, depending on how you call this function.

Try this:

```
function submitLikeForm()  {
    var form = $("#like_form");

    $.ajax({ 
    type: "GET", 
    url: form.attr("action"), 
    data: form.serialize(), 
    success:   function() {
        //
    }
    });

    // dont actually submit through to the action url
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is the default submit action of the image input type.

For ajax callbacks I would recommend using a link rather than a "submit" button.

```
<a class='like_button'><img ... /></a>
```

and as you're using jQuery bind your event to it's click event and prevent the default action.

```
jQuery('.like_button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitLikeForm();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitLikeForm()  {
        event.preventDefault();
        var form = jQuery("#like_form");
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "GET", 
                url: form.attr("action"), 
                data: form.serialize(), 
                success:   function() 
            });
        }
    </script>
```

To know more about event.preventDefault() [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_preventdefault.asp)

Comment: hey guys, I tried both of your suggestions, but neither worked. Any ideas why?